# R connection issues with relative path and executable jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, relative-path, executable-jar, rserve

I am writing a `Java` application in IntelliJ IDE. The application uses `Rserve()` to connect to `R` and access scripts. First question is: At the moment, my `R` scripts are directly under my main java project folder. To access a `R` script, I create a `RConnection` and then use the following code:

```
RConnection rc1 = new RConnection();
rc1.assign("parseFile", currentPath.concat("/parseFile.R"));
rc1.eval("source(parseFile)");
```

The `currentPath` variable in the code is the absolute path, which I obtain using this:

```
 final String currentPath = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
```

However, I want to make changes in my code and would like to access my `R` scripts using relative path. For this, I created a folder named `rscripts` in the `src` folder and placed my `R` scripts in this folder. I then marked this directory as `Sources root` using the `Mark directory as` option in intelliJ. To access the scripts I made the following changes to the code:

```
rc1.assign("parseFile", "/rscripts/parseFile.R");
rc1.eval("source(parseFile)");
```

However, now I get the error:

```
org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException: eval failed, request status: error code: 127
```

Looking at the error, it seems that `R` script cannot be accessed. 
How should I use relative paths to access the `R` scripts?

Secondly, I want to deliver my application as a jar file. Should I also bundle `R` with the `jar` file, in case the user does not have R installed on the system?

Comment: Starting with a slash means absolute path. I would just read the file contents to string in Java and eval that, seems like few things to go wrong that way

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you should change your R working directory to the correct location using setwd(). After this you can suffice with passing only the file name to the source() function.